# Using .so file in Android app

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have an .so file that I added to Android Studio 2.1.1. Everything is working well and I can call the method from the .so file. The only thing is that for it to work I need to call the native method from a very specific part in my app.

Eg the method name is `Java_com_test_app_MainView_myMethod`, and so I must call `myMethod` from a class called `MainView` in a package named `com.test.app`.

So if I rename `MainView` to `SubView` I get `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: com.test.app.SubView.myMethod`.

Is this supposed to work like this, or am I missing something?

Comment: _"Is this supposed to work like this"_. Pretty much, yeah. Some IDEs might aid you in doing this kind of renaming. You could also look into using `registerNatives` in your native code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed supposed to work like this. JNI method names must mirror the JAVA method names in `_` format.

From [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html#resolving_native_method_names) doc, following rules must be observed:

> Resolving Native Method Names
>
> Dynamic linkers resolve entries based on their names. A native method name is concatenated from the following components:
>
> - a mangled fully-qualified class name
> - an underscore (“_”) separator
> - a mangled method name
> - for overloaded native methods, two underscores (“__”) followed by the mangled argument signature

Comment: So if I had several .so files that used different fully-qualified class names, then I wouldn't be able to use them within the same class in my app? Using Xamarin I don't have that issue because instead of calling `myMethod` within `com.test.app.MainView`, I use straight `Java_com_test_app_MainView_myMethod`. So no such thing is possible in Java?

Comment: @user276648 We can usually circumvent this problem by having all the native methods being called from a single class, though it may not be always possible to do this, especially if the native method uses a java object reference. In all other cases, this solution is feasible IMO

Comment: OK so it means I can't really reuse an .so file from another project. I should instead recreate a new one each time, with the correct fully-qualified class name.